# C++ Segmentation Fault with no pointers (HackerRank)

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I solved a problem in Hacker Rank.

> **Input Format.** The first line of the input contains an integer N.The next line contains N space separated integers.The third line contains a single integer x,denoting the position of an element that should be removed from the vector.The fourth line contains two integers a and b denoting the range that should be erased from the vector inclusive of a and exclusive of b.
>
> **Output Format.** Print the size of the vector in the first line and the elements of the vector after the two erase operations in the second line separated by space.

CODE:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 0, x = 0, value = 0;
    vector<int> vk, vm;
    vk.reserve(100000);
    string k, m;
    
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, k);
    cin >> x;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, m);

    stringstream sk(k);
    while (sk >> value)
        vk.push_back(value);

    stringstream sm(m);
    while (sm >> value)
        vm.push_back(value);

    vk.erase(vk.begin() + x-1);
    vk.erase(vk.begin() + vm[0]-1, vk.begin() + vm[1]-1);

    cout << vk.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < vk.size(); i++)
        cout << vk[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But with this test case produce a "Segmentation Fault":

```
6
1 4 6 2 8 9
2
2 4
```

Can you help me to review my code and provide some feedback on what is the problem?

**EDIT**

> Thanks to @john for the answer. Here is how it looks without the seg fault:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, value = 0;
    vector<int> vk;
    vk.reserve(100000);
    
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> value;
        vk.push_back(value);
    }
    cin >> x >> y >> z;
    
    vk.erase(vk.begin() + x-1);
    vk.erase(vk.begin() + y-1, vk.begin() + z-1);

    cout << vk.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < vk.size(); i++)
        cout << vk[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see, it was suggested and only click on it. Already deleted.

Comment: It is working for me for the same test case.

Comment: Yes, also for me in my laptop, but on hacker rank website show the seg fault. That was weird in the beginning, but with the answer provided by @john now is clear what is the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying too hard with the your input code. It isn't correct because you seem to be assuming that `cin.ignore()` will skip the rest of the line, when it only skips the next character (which could be a space). I would guess this is the reason for the seg fault. You can tell how many numbers you have to read after you've read the first one. There is no need to use `getline` or `stringsteam` at all.

You don't need the vm vector. It will always contain two values, so just declare two variables. You could also pick much better names for all your variables.

```
cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    cin >> value;
    vk.push_back(value);
}
cin >> x >> vm0 >> vm1;
```

Comment: Thanks man! I'm learning C++, this is my first week. It is working now you are right with you point and explanation, that's the issue.

Comment: ...Save for the `using namespace std;`. Please don't do that @lohhenzo !